# Scale Tool Not Scaling Inwards - Only Scales Face Size

Tags: transforms, edges, faces

I've been trying to scale some faces inwards while working on the accessory rail for an M4 rifle model. However, every time I try to scale the corner faces inwards, they scale individually instead of all of them moving to the center of the object. My pivot point is correctly centered as well as the origin point. I have a feeling this is easy to correct but I'm new to Blender and have been working on Maya so I'm still inexperienced.

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.[image: Normal front side view of rifle][image: Example of faces scaling independently instead of moving towards the center of the object]

Answer (score 3):

It scales faces individually because *Individual Origins* is selected in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel, instead of *Median Point* for example:

[image]